# Powershell: Two diffrent outputs .xml

Tags: powershell

I was trying to Export a .xml-File to a .csv-File (multiple .xml-Files to one .csv-File)
This is my working code:

```
$path = "\\stos-matrix-srv\ablage$\zert_check"
$FileLogdate = Get-Date -format 'dd_MM_yyyy'
$exportpath = "C:\Temp\Cert\$FileLogdate-expordt.csv"
Get-ChildItem $path -filter *.xml |
    ForEach-Object {
        [xml]$empDetails = Get-Content $_.Fullname
            [pscustomobject]@{
            'Client' = [string]$empDetails.Objs.Obj.MS.S.innerText;
            'CertificateExpire' = [string]$empDetails.Objs.Obj.MS.DT.InnerText;
        } |  Export-CSV -Append -Path $exportpath -NoTypeInformation   
    }
```

Now I have the problem, that there can be multiple entrys at Client and Cerificate like that:

```
<Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04">
  <Obj RefId="0">
    <TN RefId="0">
      <T>Selected.System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2</T>
      <T>System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject</T>
      <T>System.Object</T>
    </TN>
    <MS>
      <DT N="NotAfter">2022-12-31T08:21:10+01:00</DT>
      <S N="Subject">Client 01</S>
      <S N="Issuer">DOMAIN</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
  <Obj RefId="1">
    <TNRef RefId="0" />
    <MS>
      <DT N="NotAfter">2022-12-31T08:21:10+01:00</DT>
      <S N="Subject">Client 01</S>
      <S N="Issuer">DOMAIN</S>
    </MS>
  </Obj>
</Objs>
```

How can i solve that the output is not like:

```
"Client 01 Client 01", "Client 01 Client 01", "2022-12-31T08:21:10+01:00 2022-12-31T08:21:10+01:00"
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the objects, e.g.:

```
$empDetails.Objs.Obj | 
% {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    "Client"            = $_.ms.s.innertext
    "CertificateExpire" = $_.ms.dt.innertext
  }
} |
ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Output:

```
"Client","CertificateExpire"
"Client 01","2022-12-31T08:21:10+01:00"
"Client 01","2022-12-31T08:21:10+01:00"
```

Comment: Is there a way to seperate two equal objects?
for example:
<S N="Subject">Client 01</S> and <S N="Issuer">DOMAIN</S>
There are both in the same <objs>